# Managing Sidekiq workers for multiple environments in Heroku using procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, procfile

[The Heroku docs indicate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#setting-local-environment-variables) that you can set environment variables for use in the procfile. I'm attempting to do set a SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY variable, so that my staging environment allots fewer workers for Sidekiq than my production environment.

I set the new variables like so:

```
heroku config:set SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY=3 --app mystaging
heroku config:set SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY=15 --app myproduction
```

Then I added the following line to my procfile:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c ENV[SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY]
```

I also tried this:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY
```

And when I deploy I get the following error in my logs:

```
invalid value for Integer(): "ENV[SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY]"
```

Comment: odd - I use `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY` which works for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you look at the Heroku resources page for your app under Dynos, do you see `worker bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY` or do you see `worker bundle exec sidekiq -c` and then the integer?

Comment: cut and paste from my resources page - bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this out, `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c $SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY` does work. I redeployed and the error resolved.